# TeamViewer moving all windows into currently viewed monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, teamviewer

I believe this may be a new feature but I would very much like to disable it.

I have three monitors and anything I launch automatically gets moved into the screen I am currently viewing despite me having specifically placed it elsewhere before closing it last.

I would like for apps that were last closed off-screen to still launch off-screen.

I am running the latest beta version (11).

Comment: Have you tried a different version of Teamviewer besides the beta version(s)?

Comment: In the past yes. That could be the difference but I'm hoping that there is a software switch somewhere for this. If not, I'll definitely be going back to the stable release.